# java.nio.file.InvalidPathException: Malformed input or input contains unmappable characters

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I'm trying to download a pdf file from Spring endpoint. I tried this:

```
@RequestMapping("/download_files/{merchant_id}")
    public ResponseEntity<byte[]> downloadFile(@PathVariable("merchant_id") Integer merchant_id) throws IOException {
     File initialFile = new File("/opt/1/www.pdf");
        InputStream in = FileUtils.openInputStream(initialFile);

        final HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
        headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_PDF);

        return new ResponseEntity<byte[]>(IOUtils.toByteArray(in), headers, HttpStatus.CREATED);
    }
```

But I get error:

```
2019-08-20 21:02:25,658 INFO  [stdout] (default task-307) java.nio.file.InvalidPathException: Malformed input or input contains unmappable characters: /opt/1/25084 BRP (BrookfieldDC.com Site Architecture & Creative?Phase 2) Autoresponders (1).pdf
```

Do you know how I can fix this issue?

Comment: My guess is the  `&` is causing the issue.

Comment: There is no & into the file title.

Comment: Well the error seems to think there is, assuming I'm reading it right: `/opt/1/25084 BRP (BrookfieldDC.com Site Architecture & Creative?Phase 2) Autoresponders (1).pdf`